# How to get printer manufacturer and model from Win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi, printing

I have eight different printers installed on a Windows 8.1 computer. These printers are various manufacturers and models, there are two HP LaserJet printers, an Epson inkjet, a CutePDF Writer, a Windows Fax printer, and others.

For all of my printers, this call to [DeviceCapabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183552(v=vs.85).aspx) returns -1, which means "either that the capability is not supported or there was a general function failure". Other `fwCapability` values, like `DC_DUPLEX`, succeed.

```
DeviceCapabilities(pDevice, pPort, DC_MANUFACTURER, NULL, &devMode);
```

My guess is that `DC_MANUFACTURER` and `DC_MODEL` are "newer" and therefore unimplemented. CUPS has a `printer-make-and-model` attribute, required PPD options `Manufacturer` and `Model`.

**What is the proper way to query the manufacturer and model of a printer with Win32?**

Comment: Do you specifically need the make and model, or are you all right with retrieving the same string the print manager uses to identify the printer?

Comment: I'll take any string that identifies, even roughly, the type of printer this is. What do you suggest?

Comment: `EnumPrinters()` lets you enumerate printers and retrieve information about them including their name. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: DC_MANUFACTURER and DC_MODEL seem to be undocumented.  Where did you come up with those?

Comment: DC_MANUFACTURER and DC_MODEL are found in WinGDI.h for WINVER >= 0x0400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DC_MANUFACTURER` and `DC_MODEL` are not listed in MSDN documentation, they are not worth investigating.

`pDevice` parameter in `DeviceCapabilities` is usually printer name and model. For example *"HP LaserJet 123"* It's the same thing in control panel. That should be all you need.

Sometimes printer name gets changed, in which case you can use driver name to identify the printer.

```
int wmain()
{
    DWORD flags = PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS;
    int level = 2;
    PRINTER_INFO_2* printerInfo;
    DWORD memsize, printer_count;

    EnumPrinters(flags, NULL, level, NULL, 0, &memsize, &printer_count);
    if (memsize < 1) return 0;

    BYTE* bytes = new BYTE[memsize];
    if (EnumPrinters(flags, NULL, level, bytes, memsize, &memsize, &printer_count))
    {
        printerInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)bytes;
        for (UINT i = 0; i < printer_count; i++)
        {
            std::wcout << "printer: " << printerInfo->pPrinterName << "\n";
            std::wcout << "printerInfo->pDriverName: " << printerInfo->pDriverName << "\n\n";
            printerInfo++;
        }
    }
    delete[] bytes;

    return 0;
}
```

In above code, `printerInfo->pPrinterName` should match printer name as shown in control panel (or `pDevice`). `printerInfo->pDriverName` should always be printer name and model.

To get the manufacturer name you can go through `DRIVER_INFO_6` and `pszMfgName` However that may not be very useful.